# Azure webapp deployment github action . Deployment failed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Trying to deploy react app to the azure web app using GitHub action & resources will be created dynamically under a single resource group which defaults to `asgithub-RG`  using service principal account as a contributor to `asgithub-RG` resource group

- Steps which I followed

1. Login with CLI
2. Create an app service plan based on PR details and name
3. Create a web app based on PR details and name
4. npm ci and npm build
5. Upload artifacts
6. Download artifacts
7. deployed to azure

*Github action*

```
name: Deploy Pull Request to Azure Web App
on:
  pull_request: 
    branches: [ "develop" ]
    types: [opened, synchronize, closed]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} # get branch name from pull request
  PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.name }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} # add GTCRM- prefix to branch name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '18-lts'                # set this to the node version to use
  RESOURCE_GROUP: 'asgithub-RG'
permissions:
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write
  actions: write

jobs:
  pre-build:
    if: github.event.action == 'opened' || github.event.action == 'synchronize' || github.event.pull_request.draft == false 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Login via Azure CLI
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    
    # Create a new resource group to hold the deployment slot
    - name: Create App service plan
      uses: Azure/cli@v1
      with: 
        inlineScript: |
          az appservice plan create --name ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}-${{ env.PR_NUMBER }}-plan --resource-group ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }} --sku B1 --is-linux

    # Set the deployment slot's app setting to point to the staging slot
    - name: Set app setting
      uses: Azure/cli@v1
      with: 
        inlineScript: |
          az webapp create --resource-group ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }} --plan ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}-${{ env.PR_NUMBER }}-plan --name ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}-${{ env.PR_NUMBER }} --runtime "NODE:${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}" --output table
          

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: pre-build
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.4.0
          cache: 'npm'

      # Cache node_modules
      - name: Cache node_modules
        uses: actions/cache@v3.1.0-beta.2
        with:
          path: '**/node_modules'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-modules-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}

       # Install dependencies
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache-node-modules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run ci --if-present
          


      # tar the build folder
      - name: Zip Package
        run: |
          zip -r node-app.zip .

      # Upload the zip file to the deployment slot
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: node-app.zip

# Deploy the zip file to the deployment slot
  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'

    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: node-app

#    #Unpack the artifact
#    - name: Unzip artifact
#      run: unzip node-app.zip

    - name: Login via Azure CLI
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2.2.5
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}-${{ env.PR_NUMBER }}
        package: node-app.zip
```

**Problem 1:**
*I executed from one GitHub repo all 7 steps are executing fine in GitHub and deployment is getting failed in the azure web app*

**logs**

```bash
2022-12-10T10:54:48.581727176Z: \[INFO\]     \____\_

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581757676Z: \[INFO\]    /  \_  \\ \_________\_ \________\_   \___\_

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581762376Z: \[INFO\]   /  /_\\  \\_\_\_   /  |  \_  \_\_ \_/ \_\_ \\

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581765977Z: \[INFO\]  /    |    /    /|  |  /|  | /\\  \__\_/

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581769477Z: \[INFO\]  \____|__  /_\___\_ \____/ |__|    \__\_  \>

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581773177Z: \[INFO\]          /      /                  /

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581776477Z: \[INFO\]  A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581779777Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581782777Z: \[INFO\]  Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581785977Z: \[INFO\]  NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581788977Z: \[INFO\]  NodeJS Version : v18.12.0

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581792277Z: \[INFO\]  Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted

2022-12-10T10:54:48.581795477Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:49.216708277Z: \[INFO\]  Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.

2022-12-10T10:54:49.446358441Z: \[INFO\]  Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.

2022-12-10T10:54:49.598691233Z: \[INFO\]  Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'

2022-12-10T10:54:49.606104102Z: \[INFO\]  Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...

2022-12-10T10:54:49.606179104Z: \[INFO\]  Build Operation ID: 5aceb568-51a8-4ee6-9f9d-835f90d52e7a

2022-12-10T10:54:50.732891663Z: \[INFO\]  Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..

2022-12-10T10:54:50.895699980Z: \[INFO\]  Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128069973Z: \[INFO\]  Running #!/bin/sh

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128097374Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128102674Z: \[INFO\]  # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128106774Z: \[INFO\]  cd "/home/site/wwwroot"

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128110674Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128114474Z: \[INFO\]  export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128118574Z: \[INFO\]  if \[ -z "$PORT" \]; then

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128122474Z: \[INFO\]        export PORT=8080

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128126674Z: \[INFO\]  fi

2022-12-10T10:54:51.128130374Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:51.215962971Z: \[INFO\]  npm start

2022-12-10T10:54:53.801869544Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info it worked if it ends with ok

2022-12-10T10:54:53.803157767Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info using npm@6.14.15

2022-12-10T10:54:53.812627941Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info using node@v18.12.0

2022-12-10T10:54:55.390189353Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0\~prestart: my-app@0.1.0

2022-12-10T10:54:55.449869038Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0\~start: my-app@0.1.0

2022-12-10T10:54:55.481953221Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:55.482000722Z: \[INFO\]  \> my-app@0.1.0 start /home/site/wwwroot

2022-12-10T10:54:55.482007922Z: \[INFO\]  \> react-scripts start

2022-12-10T10:54:55.482023422Z: \[INFO\]

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161168776Z: \[ERROR\]  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161201276Z: \[ERROR\]    throw err;

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161206076Z: \[ERROR\]    ^

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161209576Z: \[ERROR\]

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161212977Z: \[ERROR\]  Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161216377Z: \[ERROR\]  Require stack:

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161220077Z: \[ERROR\]  - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161223477Z: \[ERROR\]      at Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161227477Z: \[ERROR\]      at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161235677Z: \[ERROR\]      at Object.\<anonymous\> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:31:23)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161240177Z: \[ERROR\]      at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161243577Z: \[ERROR\]      at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161246977Z: \[ERROR\]      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161250277Z: \[ERROR\]      at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161253777Z: \[ERROR\]      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161257177Z: \[ERROR\]      at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161260578Z: \[ERROR\]    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161263878Z: \[ERROR\]    requireStack: \[ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts' \]

2022-12-10T10:54:57.161267278Z: \[ERROR\]  }

2022-12-10T10:54:57.171300295Z: \[ERROR\]

2022-12-10T10:54:57.171322096Z: \[ERROR\]  Node.js v18.12.0

2022-12-10T10:54:57.240925304Z: \[ERROR\]  npm info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0\~start: Failed to exec start script

2022-12-10T10:54:57.262303367Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2022-12-10T10:54:57.270736750Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! errno 1

2022-12-10T10:54:57.331226561Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

2022-12-10T10:54:57.331244961Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! Exit status 1

2022-12-10T10:54:57.331249462Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR!

2022-12-10T10:54:57.331261062Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.

2022-12-10T10:54:57.331264962Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2022-12-10T10:54:57.343324323Z: \[ERROR\]  npm timing npm Completed in 4353ms

2022-12-10T10:54:57.343341624Z: \[ERROR\]

2022-12-10T10:54:57.343346224Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2022-12-10T10:54:57.343350024Z: \[ERROR\]  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/\_logs/2022-12-10T10_54_57_310Z-debug.log
```

**Problem 2:**
*Just to try with create react app i will same github action and credentials it is failing after login on step 2*

**logs**

```bash
Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.42.0
ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/azwebappci-feature' under resource group 'azwebapp' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/azwebappci-feature' under resource group 'azwebapp' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Error: Error: az cli script failed.
cleaning up container...
MICROSOFT_AZURE_CLI_1670667478073_CONTAINER

Error: az cli script failed.
```

**Expectation ==>**

1. Script should be compatible with all repo to create dynamic resources
2. Why has deployment is getting failed

As a workaround, I think of App service container deployment or host build folder on Static website .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it appears that the problem is that it cannot find the manifest file:

> Cound not find build manifest file at
> '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'

I would do the following to isolate the problem:

1. Find where the file is on your local machine
2. Make sure that it is checked in to source control
3. Find where the file is referenced and check that that location is available

Comment: How it can be resolved? I simply want to deploy react app

Comment: Also check the contents of your log file